# Show/Hide Submenu by click

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have this part of my code in sidebar.component.html :

```
 <ul class="nav">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
                <i class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</i>
                <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
            </a>
            <ng-container *ngIf="menuItem.children && menuItem.children.length > 0">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let childmenu of menuItem.children"
                        class="{{menuItem.class}}">
                        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[childmenu.path]">
                            <p>{{childmenu.title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ng-container>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and this is my code in sidebar.component.css :

```
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
  { path: '/dashboard', title: 'dashbord', icon: 'dashboard', class: '', children: '' },
  {
    path: '/user-List', title: 'Parent', icon: 'apps', class: '', children: [
      { path: '#', title: 'Child Menu 1', icon: 'dashboard', class: '' },
      { path: '#', title: 'Child Menu 2', icon: 'add_shopping_cart', class: '' },
      { path: '#', title: 'Child Menu 3', icon: 'sports_soccer', class: '' },
    ]
  }
];
```

can you help me please to show/hide submenu by click  ?

Comment: Show/hide it by clicking what?

Comment: by click on the mouse

Comment: Yes but clicking what? Clicking anywhere on the screen, or a button in the same component or a button in a different component?

Comment: By click " Parent" i want show or hide the submenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent component ts file create a property to store the submenu state:

```
showSubMenu: boolean = false;
```

In you parent template give your sub-menu an *ngIf and a button to toggle it:

```
<button (click)="showSubMenu = !showSubMenu">Toggle Sub Menu</button>
<sub-menu *ngIf="showSubMenu"></sub-menu>
```